# I need some C++ structure advice

Tags: c++, pointers

I have one instance of Class A. It has two members, Object A and Object B. I need to create ONE instance of Object A (which is quite a large object), and TWO instances of object B, and then give both instances of object B access to that object A. They don't ever need to change object A, they just need to access its info.

Right now, I got it all to work by creating Object A as a pointer, passing it into both instances of Object B, who have their own pointer that then points to the same place in memory as Object A's pointer. This works fine, but I think that's a pretty big No-No right? Because once Class A deletes the original pointer I'll have some dangling pointers, right? Is there a better way to do this?

(FYI - Object A takes a couple seconds to load at a time in the program where I need a fast load time, that's why I have to create only one instance and pass it to both of Object Bs instead of letting Object B create their own instances of Object A. )

Comment: Can you post the code instead of description?

Comment: Please please please don't have a class `A` and also an object of name `A`. Pretend that SO consists of hyperactive zero-attention span nervous wrecks who get badly confused if you give them obfuscated code. The same goes for `class MyClass` and `class myClass_ : public MyClass`... the simpler, the better! Popular past names have been `Foo` and `Bar`.

Comment: if class A has an object A and an object B, why do you need two object Bs and one object A? It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Be more precise in your description: what's "an instance of object B"?

Comment: Sorry! This has been quite a lesson in etiquette. My questions was answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you want something like this:

```
// Class for "Object A" in your question
class Foo
{
    // ...
};

// Class for "Object B" in your question
class Bar
{
    Foo &foo_;

public:
    Bar(Foo &foo)
        : foo_(foo)
        {}
};

class A
{
    Foo foo_;
    Bar bar1_;
    Bar bar2_;

public:
    A()
        : bar1_(foo_),
          bar2_(foo_)
        {}
};
```

Using no pointers, no allocations, so no dangling pointers/references or memory leaks. When `A` gets destroyed so does `bar1_` and `bar2_` too along with `foo_`, so the two instances of `Bar` will not be left with any dangling references either.

Comment: OK, my code is structured like that, so I'm good. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Provided that the "B-things" don't outlive the "big object that they both have a pointer to", then you won't have a dangling pointer when the "big object" is deleted.

If "one instance of Class A" has both of those objects as data members, then they'll all be destroyed at the same time (well, in reverse order that they're declared in the class, but close to the same time), so it should be reasonably easy to ensure that the dangling pointer is never used.

On the other hand, if you pass pointers to the "big object" around willy-nilly, store them in all sorts of different places with unknown lifetimes, and then delete the "big object" -- sure, that's a no-no. The problem is "willy-nilly" - you need to keep control and make sure that the big object outlives the objects that point to it.

For example, the following is perfectly safe:

```
struct Big {
    // big stuff
};

struct Little {
    Little(const Big *a) : bigthing(a) {}
    // stuff that uses bigthing
  private:
    const Big *bigthing;
};

struct Foo {
    Big onlybigthing;
    Little firstlittlething;
    Little secondlittlething;
    Foo() : 
        onlybigthing(), 
        firstlittlething(&onlybigthing), 
        secondlittlething(&onlybigthing) 
    {}
};
```

provided of course that the instances of `Little` don't hand out their pointer to `Big`, to anyone who comes asking for it and then stores it beyond the lifetime of the `Foo` object. Likewise `Foo` has to avoid handing out copies of the instances of `Little` to someone who might store those (and the pointer with them).

But you say that your class A has *two* members, whereas here I have three (one `Big` and two `Little`) because you also say that you create three instances of those two objects. I don't understand what that means.

Here's another example of something that's safe:

```
int main() {
    Big big;
    Little little1(&big);
    Little little2(&big);
}
```

Here's a third example of something that's safe:

```
struct Little {
    Little(const std::shared_ptr<Big> &a) : bigthing(a) {}
    // stuff that uses bigthing
  private:
    std::shared_ptr<Big> bigthing;
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Big> big(new Big());
    Little little1(big);
    Little little2(big);
    big.reset(); // release our shared ownership
    // safely do stuff using little1 and little2

    return 0;
    // on exit, little2 is destroyed first, then when little1 is destroyed
    // it releases the last shared ownership of the instance of `Big`,
    // which is destroyed.
}
```

Comment: My code is structured like your first example. So I'm good. Thanks.